# copy long text area field on Account object to Opportunities object's field

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

New bee.

I need to copy **Long Text Area field** - Quote_Methods__c at **Account** Level to **Opportunity** Level field - Quote_Instruc__c.
I know it be cannot be done by formula, and workflow/process builder is work around but I need something that changes the field data at opportunity level dynamically, when the data in Quote_Methods__c at Account level is changes. It should apply to all child records [opportunities]. I think can be done by **before update** trigger on Account by using try and catch error method but not that expert in coding level. Please help me with sample code/ anything. I appreciate your time and help.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 2):

**Your requirement can be achieved by Process Builder**

These are the steps:

**Choose Object**

*Account (Start the process = When a record is created or edited)*
[image]

**Define Criteria**

*Account.Quote_Methods__c is changed*

[image]

**Update Records**

*Records [Account.Opportunities]*

Field:
*Quote_Instruc reference [Account].Quote_Methods__c*

[image]

If any changes made on Quote_Methods__c of Account record, it will update Quote_Instruc__c of all the opportunities.

**By the way, in case you want to update any specific opportunities then Trigger is the only option.**

Comment: Thank you so much for solution. I really appreciate it. But I looking for something that updates dynamically [without need to edit the child records to see changes of parent object field]. Something that acts like formula field.

Comment: @Gidy your requirement is not clear. Read about capabilities of Formula, Process Builder and Trigger

Comment: Mark the suitable  best answer and close your question

Comment: I'm not still clear with answer cropredy is helping me out... thank you so much for your time and wouldn't think you sound pleasing, hope at least you will be sound polite to the people in future

Comment: We people are professionals, don't try to please anybody here

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below trigger:

```
trigger demoTrigger on Account(before update){
    list<opportunity> oplist = new list<opportunity>();
    for(account acc : [select id, Quote_Methods__c, (select id, Quote_Instruc__c from opportunities) from account where id IN: trigger.new )]){
        for(opportunity op : acc.opportunities){
            if(acc.Quote_Methods__c != null){
                op.Quote_Instruc__c = acc.Quote_Methods__c;
                oplist.add(op);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!oplist.oisEmpty()){
        update oplist;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: N.B. - the `isEmpty` test is superfluous (and has a typo also) - SFDC does not consumer DML governor limits on empty lists

Comment: @cropredy: I think it worked but I have a question though. Does it update dynamically like the formula field. For example, If you do changes on field which does have formula linked to child field, it changes data on child field too [no need to perform action on child record to see the change]. So, does it do something same?? Does it also update the child field if we delete data on parent field??

Comment: @Gidy - (1) above trigger, for each Account in trigger set, pushes the value of `Account.Quote_Methods__c` into all children `Opportunity.Quote_Instruc__c`. (2) If `Account.Quote_Methods__c` is cleared, the above trigger _does not_ clear the children Opportunities `Quote_Instruc__c`.

Comment: @cropredy ... so if I change something at account level "Account.Quote_Methods__c it pushes into all children Opportunity.Quote_Instruc__c dynamically. I mean like formula field. Would I see the changes without or even before I click edit Opportunity record?

How can I make it happen to delete/clear the children Opportunities.Quote_Instruc__c on deleting/clear of Account.Quote_Methods__c?

Comment: @Gidy just try the process builder, your this requirement will work

Comment: @SantanuBoral .... Please read I what posted

Comment: @Gidy (1) _so if I change something at account level Account.Quote_Methods__c it pushes into all children Opportunity.Quote_Instruc__c dynamically. I mean like formula field. Would I see the changes without or even before I click edit Opportunity record?_  The changes will be committed as soon as the Account Save event is finished. No need to open the child Oppo.  (2) _How can I make it happen to delete/clear the children Opportunities.Quote_Instruc__c on deleting/clear of Account.Quote_Methods__c?_  Look at answer - just remove the `if(acc.Quote_Methods__c != null)`

Comment: @cropredy ... the solution you provided is kinda working but not instantaneous. After changing the field value at parent object, it's taking time to update/replicate the child's field value.

Comment: @Gidy - mark this answer as the solution and post a different question about performance issues - show code you are using and measurement of time to complete as your context is not clear and a comment thread is not the way to conclude this